# Multiple get requests with request-json not executing properly with async in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

My requirement is that I need to load JSON data from multiple REST resources. For this I need to make multiple get requests. I need to perform some function when all the requests have been completed.

Below is my code:

```
var asyncTasks = [];
//These URLs are dynamic and can increase or decrease
var urls = ["resource1", "resource2", "resource3"];
var client = request.createClient("domainurl");

urls.forEach(function (item) {
    asyncTasks.push(function () {
        client.get(item, function (err, res, body) {
            dataLoaded(err, res, body)
        });
    });
});

async.parallel(asyncTasks, function () {
    // All tasks are done now
    allDataLoaded();
});

function dataLoaded(err, res, body) {
console.log('Data Loaded');
};

function allDataLoaded() {
console.log("All data loaded");
}
```

The issue I am facing is that the `allDataLoaded` function is not called, although the `dataLoaded` functions are being called correctly.

I am using request-json and async npm packages for this.
Thanks for your time, please let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: Why is this tagged [promise]?

Comment: It has been removed. Thanks for pointing out. cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`async.parallel` passes a callback to every task which you need to call, otherwise it cannot know when your task has finished. Use

```
var asyncTasks = urls.map(function (item) {
    return function (cb) {
//                   ^^
        client.get(item, function (err, res, body) {
            dataLoaded(err, res, body)
            cb(err);
//          ^^^^^^^
        });
    };
});
```

then `async.parallel(asyncTasks, allDataLoaded)` will work.